# Display two Reclerview in single activty with same recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have two List coming from webservice Like past and future.Sometimes both List have data and sometime only one list have data. And how set the differt RecyclerView for pastList and FuturList with same adapter.

Comment: Can you provide an extract of code that illustrate your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your model objects are the same, it sounds like you need to have two versions of the adapter, where you can assign each list of data to each different adapter.

So if your adapter was `MyObjectRecyclerViewAdapter`, you could make two instances - `pastObjectsAdapter = MyObjectRecyclerViewAdapter();
futureObjectsAdapter = MyOjbectRecyclerViewAdapter();`

Then assign one to each of your `RecyclerView`s and update the list on each with your lists from your webservice.